# Can not receive POST data in nodeJs

Tags: node.js, http-post, http-get

I am beginner of nodeJs. I just want to receive GET and POST data in nodeJs.

I tried and Get GET data successfully but In POST data I'm getting error **ReferenceError: setImmediate is not defined**.
When I run server.js using `$ node server.js` it will listen at `3000` port and redirect to `index.html` page and Through an error.

I did Google for it but No solution found for my error.

I'm attaching code.

**server.js**

```
var express        =         require("express");
var bodyParser     =         require("body-parser");
var app            =         express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html");
});
app.post('/login',function(req,res){
  var user_name=req.body.user;
  var password=req.body.password;
  console.log("User name = "+user_name+", password is "+password);
  res.end("yes");
});
app.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log("Started on PORT 3000");
})
```

**package.json**

```
 {
  "dependencies":
  {
    "express":"*",
    "body-parser":"*"
  }
}
```

**index.html**

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple login</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">  </script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var user,pass;
        $("#submit").click(function(){
          user=$("#user").val();
          pass=$("#password").val();
          $.post("http://localhost:3000/login",{user: user,password: pass}, function(data){
            if(data==='done')
              {
                alert("login success");
              }
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello people !</h1>
    <input type="TEXT" id="user" size="40"><br>
    <input type="password" id="password" size="40"><br>
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit">
  </body>
</html>
```

The Error I'm getting :

```
Started on PORT 3000

/var/www/html/nodeJs/Example-4/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1013
    setImmediate(function () {
    ^
ReferenceError: setImmediate is not defined
    at Array.onfinish [as 0] (/var/www/html/nodeJs/Example-4/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1013:5)
    at listener (/var/www/html/nodeJs/Example-4/node_modules/express/node_modules/on-finished/index.js:169:15)
    at onFinish (/var/www/html/nodeJs/Example-4/node_modules/express/node_modules/on-finished/index.js:100:5)
    at callback (/var/www/html/nodeJs/Example-4/node_modules/express/node_modules/on-finished/node_modules/ee-first/index.js:55:10)
    at ServerResponse.onevent (/var/www/html/nodeJs/Example-4/node_modules/express/node_modules/on-finished/node_modules/ee-first/index.js:93:5)
    at ServerResponse.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:126:20)
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage._finish (http.js:837:8)
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.end (http.js:822:10)
    at onend (stream.js:66:10)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:126:20)
```

Comment: You must be using an ancient version of node (pre-v0.10). You can verify this with `node -v` at your shell prompt.

Comment: @mscdex My machine have node v0.8.15...
How can i upgrade it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ancient versions of node (pre-v0.10) did not support `setImmediate()`, so you will need to upgrade your copy of node for the code to work.

To upgrade node, see [this page](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/) about adding a repository (or using an installer for OS X or Windows) to keep your copy of node up to date automatically. Alternatively, you can either extract a precompiled binary tarball to a place of your choosing (adjusting your `$PATH` as necessary) or compile and install from source. For these options see [this page](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/).

Comment: I've node 0.8.15 version and i want to upgrade it.
I use this command 'sudo npm install npm -g' but i fail to upgrate.